# Why cursorLoader didn't notify changes in source data?

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter, android-cursor

I have a simple contentProvider, a layout with a ListView and a button for adding Items in content Provider and a CursorLoader. The [android.content.Loader, D](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks.html#onLoadFinished) reference states that

> The Loader will monitor for changes to the data, and report them to
> you through new calls here. You should not monitor the data yourself.
> For example, if the data is a Cursor and you place it in a
> CursorAdapter, use the CursorAdapter(android.content.Context,
> android.database.Cursor, int) constructor without passing in either
> FLAG_AUTO_REQUERY or FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER (that is, use 0
> for the flags argument). This prevents the CursorAdapter from doing
> its own observing of the Cursor, which is not needed since when a
> change happens you will get a new Cursor throw another call here.

But the Log.info line in the onLoadFinished method was not executed and listView didn't refreshed. Here is my (simple) code:

```
public class HomeActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{
static final String TAG = "HomeActivity";
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
ListView listAnnunciVicini;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home);

    listAnnunciVicini = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista_annunci_vicini);

    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, null, 
            new String[] {
                    ContentDescriptor.Annunci.Cols.ID, 
                    ContentDescriptor.Annunci.Cols.TITOLO, 
                    ContentDescriptor.Annunci.Cols.DESCRIZIONE 
            }, new int[] { 
                    R.id.list_annunci_item_id_annuncio, 
                    R.id.list_annunci_item_titolo_annuncio,
                    R.id.list_annunci_item_descrizione_annuncio
            }, 0);
    listAnnunciVicini.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Prepare the loader. Either re-connect with an existing one,
    // or start a new one.
    getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this).forceLoad();
}

public void addRandomItem(View sender) {
    ContentValues dataToAdd = new ContentValues();
    dataToAdd.put(ContentDescriptor.Annunci.Cols.TITOLO, "Titolo");
    dataToAdd.put(ContentDescriptor.Annunci.Cols.DESCRIZIONE, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.");
    this.getContentResolver().insert(ContentDescriptor.Annunci.CONTENT_URI, dataToAdd);
}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    // creating a Cursor for the data being displayed.
    String[] proiezione = new String[] {ContentDescriptor.Annunci.Cols.ID, ContentDescriptor.Annunci.Cols.TITOLO, ContentDescriptor.Annunci.Cols.DESCRIZIONE };
    
    CursorLoader cl = new CursorLoader(this, ContentDescriptor.Annunci.CONTENT_URI, proiezione, null, null, null);
    return cl;
}

public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    // Swap the new cursor in.  (The framework will take care of closing the
    // old cursor once we return.)
    adapter.swapCursor(data);
    Log.i(TAG, "I dati sono stati ricaricati");
}

public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    // This is called when the last Cursor provided to onLoadFinished()
    // above is about to be closed.  We need to make sure we are no
    // longer using it.
    adapter.swapCursor(null);
}
}
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

AFAIK, you need to implement notification yourself in `ContentProvider`. For this, add something like `getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);` to `insert`,`update` and `delete` method of `ContentProvider` and invoke`.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri)` on your `Cursor` in `query`as described in [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html#query%28android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%29). [Here](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/13/writing-your-own-contentprovider/) you can find the whole picture.

**Note:** You should not close the cursor (`cursor.close()`) in order to get
 notifications about the changes.

Comment: I'm using the new Loaders API of Android 3.X+ because the old managedQuery method is deprecated. And I've notifyChange method in my ContentProvider too..

Comment: I always forget to setNotificationUri in my query and always wonder why cursor loader isnt refreshing... :-|